# fetching an image from a https link

Tags: ios, ssl, https

I have just started learning ios development, and I am trying to get an image from website which uses ssl, when i connect to the site through a browser(laptop) there is a warning which says that the root certificate is not trusted, I am not the owner of the website, however I can fully trust it.
My first attempt:

```
self.eventImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
[NSURL  URLWithString:imageUrl]]];
```

so I get this error

> NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)

I have tried to send users to the picture link by starting ios web browser, when they do that, they would get a message asking them if they could trust it or not, if they hit yes the image will appear, however i want the image to appear inside the application.

I have also tried to use web view but it didn't work.

Most of the similar questions in here suggested using this

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)
  connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: 
  (NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return NO;
    //return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:
    //         NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)
  connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:
  (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
     NSString *imageUri =[self.detailItem objectForKey: @"image"];
     NSArray *trustedHosts = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:imageUri, nil];
     if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod   
         isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
               [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:
                challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:
                challenge];

 [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

but these two methods were never called when I add them.

Comment: Why do you expect those `connection:...` methods to be called? You are not using `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: A correct answer depends on whether you want to effectively disable server trust evaluation (as it has been done in your sample). If you really want this, you don't get the benefits of using a secure connection. This is by no means recommended. For more info please read here: [Overriding TLS Chain Validation Correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html).

Comment: That is, you are developing an app solely for your own purpose? Or just for getting experience? Fine, but for any real app it's considered mandatory these days to use a secure connection, no matter what. But don't worry, we are here to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code. Instead of using `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:` you need to use your own explicit `NSURLConnection`. Then you can make use of the appropriate `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods.

Another option is to use the popular [AFNetworking library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: The real question is how to implement the delegates correctly. Using `NSURLConnection` delegate approach or AFNetworking won't solve this automatically.

Comment: Right. But step 1 needs to be fixed before step 2 can be addressed.

Comment: I suggest step 2 should become a separate question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these two methods

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
[challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: But the OP isn't using an `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

rmaddy, user2179059, and Anindya Sengupta answers helped in resolving this issue.

first, i used `NSURLConnection` explicitly, and for the secure connection i used this approach ( got it from this  [blog post](http://www.crowleyworks.com/mobile/secure/ios) )

```
-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:
(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
        isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:
(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
      isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
      // instead of XXX.XXX.XXX, add the host URL, 
      // if this didn't work, print out the error you receive.
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"XXX.XXX.XXX"]) {
        NSLog(@"Allowing bypass...");
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:
                                       challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential
             forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
 }
[challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

this differ from user2179059 by limiting unsecure connection to that host only.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have included the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol in the interface in .h file?

```
@interface ConnectionExampleViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

Comment: This has no bearing on the issue. The OP isn't even using `NSURLConnection`. The code is using `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:`.