# NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) iOS

Tags: ios, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Currently I am consuming a soap web service using block in ios my source code is as follows

```
NSString *xml = requestXMLToSent;

NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[xml length]];
NSURL *serviceURL = [NSURL URLWithString: url];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceURL];

[urlRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest addValue: serviceURL forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[urlRequest addValue:msgLength  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody: [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {


    if (connectionError == NULL) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        NSInteger statuscode = httpResponse.statusCode;
        if (statuscode == 200) {

            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"response String  : %@",responseString);


        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",response);

        }




    }else{

        NSLog(@"There is an error in URL connection and the Error is : %@",connectionError);
    }
```

I am getting the following error @ console

```
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

There is an error in URL connection and the Error is : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.xxxxxxxx.net” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x10948bbb0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x109470d10 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.xxxxxx.net” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https: // www.----------------------------------, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https: // ------------------------- NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.xxxxxx.net” which could put your confidential information at risk.}

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941939/fetching-an-image-from-a-https-link

Comment: @iPatel How can i sort it out if I am using block
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:<#(NSURLRequest *)#> queue:<#(NSOperationQueue *)#> completionHandler:<#^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)handler#>]

Answer (score 13):

Server is throwing **SSL** certificate error.
For the sake of testing, you can add the following code to the appDelegate:
 
`+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host {
    return YES;
}`

This will bypass the SSL error

*Note: works for NSURLConnection & UIWebView, but not for WKWebView*

**Edited:**

For iOS 9, above procedure don't work. Add the following snippet in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: amazing! You saved my day!!

Comment: This is *extremely* useful information. I ran into this issue when I started compiling for iOS 9, and it was remarkably tricky to find out what was wrong. This was it.

Comment: this works for iOS 9.x, but on iOS 10.x it fails again. Does anyone know the resolution for iOS 10?

Comment: Unable to make it work on iOS 10.x. I haven't found any working solutions online.

Answer (score 9):

I assume you use https scheme in your serviceURL and your test server has problems with SSL certificate. If so and you trust it, implement next methods in your `NSURLConnection` delegate's:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"127.0.0.1"] /*check if this is host you trust: */ )
       [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

To have a delegate initialize your `NSURLConnection` for example with `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Check your delegates are actually being called.

This documentation explains that your delegates may not be getting called in certain circumstances.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html

> Important: The URL loading system classes do not call their delegates to handle request challenges unless the server response contains a WWW-Authenticate header. Other authentication types, such as proxy authentication and TLS trust validation do not require this header.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9.0 add the following to info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
     <dict>  
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
     </dict>
```

Comment: Doing this blindly without understanding the implications is a dangerous solution.