# NSURLSession HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)

Tags: ios, objective-c, server

Im trying to send data in JSON format on a server with self-signed cert from my iOS app via Objective C.  Unfortunately I get this error:

*NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)*

On this thread: [NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241872/nsurlconnection-cfurlconnection-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9813) I have found out I should add this code in my info.plist file, but it is not working for me. Btw when I remove it i got same error with number 9802.

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>`

I have also tried to implement this:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"mydomain.com"]){
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
    }
}
```

}

but I don't know how to call this method (where to get values for parameters of this function) - now I'm using

```
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
}] resume];
```

to start the session.

Im still a beginner so please sorry me if I ask some stupid question, or if something is unclear. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Also required is for the app to support IPV6 including not using hard-coded IP addresses. Suggested is to use `NSURLSession`. Otherwise exception additions must be made in the app plist.

See the WWDC-15 session "Security and your Apps".

iOS9 requires the server to only support TLSv1.2 and support perfect forward security.

Also see [Steven Peterson's](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) Blog for detailed reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for a reply. However I still don't really know what Im doing wrong. Is TLSv1.2 must in? - I thought its bypassed by NSAllowsArbitraryLoads. Is there somewhere reference of errors (what the error actually mean?)